# Load-balancing socket.io has trouble

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I've 3 server socket.io, using redis adapter and nginx for load balancing. When I test in my computer, there is only server is using, and the last two server socket.io can't be routed to ? How to test with three server routing ? Here is my code: https://github.com/lenguyenkhoi21/socketio-scale

Comment: Have you tried to test it with regular HTTP GETs to see if you NGINX actually load balancing properly? I see you have no sticky cookies configured on you nginx config so when you initiate your connection from a second computer you should receive the request on the second server.

Comment: Sorry, It seems that sticky cookies is only on nginx plus ?